# Syntax error I can't figure out? python3

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

This is my program. It tells me exactly where the the syntax error is, but I literally have no idea what the problem is:

```
import sqlite3

def create_table(dbName, table_name, sql):
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where name=?",(table_name,))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        keep_table = True
        if len(result) == 1:
            response = input("The table{0} already exists, do you wish to recreate? (y/n) \n".format(table_name))
            if response.lower() == "y":
                keep_table = False
                print("the {0} table will be recreated".format(table_name))
                cursor.execute("drop table if exists {0}".format(table_name))
                db.commit()
                insert_data()
            else:
                print("The existing table was kept")
                insert_data()
        else:
            keep_table = False
        if not keep_table:
>>>>>>      cursor.execute(sql) #Problem is supposedly here?
            db.commit()
            insert_data()

def insert_data():
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = """insert into ATM(Title, First Name, Surname, Balance) values (Mr., Jeremy, Clarkson, 172.16),
                                                                             (Miss, Suzanne, Perry, 15.62)"""
        cursor.execute(sql, values)
        db.commit()


dbName = "ATM.db"
sql = """ create table ATM
          (CustomerID integer,
          Title text
          First Name text,
          Surname text,
          Balance real,
          CustomerID(CustomerID))"""
create_table(dbName, "ATM", sql)
```

This is the syntax error message I am getting. I've put arrows in the code which highlights where it is pointing out:

```
line 23, in create_table
    cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your SQL code, not the Python.

A few things:

1. You need to end all of your `sqlite3` commands with a semicolon, or else it just keeps reading as one command. That led to confusion about where the error was.
2. Adding the semicolon, we see that the problem is actually in your `CREATE TABLE` command. This line makes no sense: `"CustomerID(CustomerID))"`. Were you intending to set a `PRIMARY KEY`?

   ```
   create table ATM (
     CustomerID integer,
     Title text
     First Name text,
     Surname text,
     Balance real,
     PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
   );
   ```

Incidentally, you have another problem.
This is your query:

```
insert into ATM(Title, First Name, Surname, Balance) values (Mr., Jeremy, Clarkson, 172.16),
                                                                         (Miss, Suzanne, Perry, 15.62)
```

The problem is that you need to wrap your strings in quotes, rather than treating them as bare words and hoping they'll be interpreted properly:

```
    insert into ATM(Title, First Name, Surname, Balance) values ("Mr.", "Jeremy", "Clarkson", 172.16),
                                                                         ("Miss", "Suzanne", "Perry", 15.62);
```

Otherwise, it's an invalid query because the bare words make it malformed.

Comment: I'm still getting the same syntax error, I realised my mistake in that query and changed it already! I even tested it by removing the whole insert data function, and I still have the same syntax error which points to     cursor.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Thank you for your help! Have a nice day!